# How to resume a suspended shell?

Tags: bash, shell

```
$ help suspend
suspend: suspend [-f]
    Suspend shell execution.

    Suspend the execution of this shell until it receives a SIGCONT signal.
```

How should I send a SIGCONT signal to a shell suspended by `suspend` in a gnome terminal tab?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Send `SIGCONT`

The only way to resume the suspended shell is to send the `SIGCONT` signal, presumably from another shell. You'll need to know the PID (process ID) of the shell.

```
kill -cont $shellpid
```

If you don't know the PID already, try this:

```
ps x | grep bash
```

For example, when I suspended my shell, I saw this with `ps x | grep bash`:

```
 6147 pts/14   S+     0:00 grep --color bash
 6172 pts/14   Ss     0:01 /bin/bash
15085 pts/0    Ss+    0:00 /bin/bash
15121 pts/12   Ts+    0:01 /bin/bash
```

Look at that third column. The shell you want is the one with the `T`, and that one has a PID (first column) of 15121. Of course the PID in your case will differ; this was just an example. Once you find the PID (let's say it *is* 15121), then run:

```
kill -cont 15121
```

Comment: What does the "T" mean?

Comment: The `T` status in [ps(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) indicates a stopped process, which in this case was stopped via the `suspend` [builtin](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Comment: `C-z` on my GUI emacs suspends it, but emacs shows up like this with `ps aux | grep emacs`:
`gauthier 21308  0.5  1.3 453984 101564 ?       Sl   15:03   0:07 /usr/bin/emacs`
I'm not sure why it says `Sl ` and not `T`?

Answer (score 12):

The same way as with any other suspended process: With `fg`, `%`, or any other similar job control builtin.

```
zsh% bash
bash$ suspend
zsh: suspended (signal)  bash
zsh% jobs
[1]  + suspended (signal)  bash
zsh% fg
[1]  + continued  bash
bash$
```

Comment: Note that `fg` will only work in the case of a subshell (i.e., job suspended by the current shell). Also, `suspend` will happily suspend the last shell in the chain without `-f` if it isn't a login shell (as is the case with a normal (local) terminal emulator shell, which is how I tested my answer). Sending a `SIGCONT` from another shell will work in both cases. (See my answer.)

Comment: @type_outcast I removed the part about `suspend`ing the last shell, since it wasn't really important, so not worth adding a clarification and making the answer longer.