# edit-and-execute-command interrupted by SIGTSTP

Tags: bash, signals, line-editor, fc

I've been using bash's [`edit-and-execute-command` function](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/bashline.c?id=3ba697465bc74fab513a26dea700cc82e9f4724e#n935):

> **`edit-and-execute-command (C-x C-e)`**
>
> Invoke an editor on the current command line, and execute the result as shell commands. Bash attempts to invoke `$VISUAL`, `$EDITOR`, and `emacs` as the editor, in that order.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html

I've noticed that if I invoke an editor,
use Ctrl-Z to put it into the background,
and then use `fg` to put it back into the foreground,
the shell no longer executes the temporary file.

This is handy if I want to abort the command,
but I found the behavior a little surprising the first time it happened.

My questions:

- Why does this happen?

  I know from the source code
  that [`edit_and_execute_command` eventually calls `fc`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/bashline.c?id=3ba697465bc74fab513a26dea700cc82e9f4724e#n957),
  but it's not immediately clear to me
  *why* sending SIGTSTP prevents bash from executing the temporary file.
- If I had accidentally hit Ctrl-Z
  and still wanted to execute the script in the temporary file still open by the editor,
  what would be the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 2):

> If I had accidentally hit `Ctrl-Z` and still wanted to execute the script in the temporary file still open by the editor, what would be the best way of doing that?

You could try using and editor wrapper which would save the last command somewhere, and a readline binding which could bring it back.
Example which saves the last buffer to `~/.last_fcedit` and binds `Esc-/` (`Alt-/`) to replace the command line with it:

```
LAST_FCEDIT=$HOME/.last_fcedit
fc(){ case $1 in -e) _fce=$2; set -- "$@" -e _fcedit; esac; command fc "$@"; }
_fcedit()("$_fce" "$@"; s=$?; test -f "$1" && mv "$1" "$LAST_FCEDIT"; exit "$s")
bind -x '"\e/":READLINE_LINE=$(<"$LAST_FCEDIT")'
```

Then

```
$ echo FOO<Ctrl-X Ctrl-E>
... in editor ...
<Ctrl-Z>
[1]+  Stopped                 ( "$_fce" "$@"; s=$?; mv "$1" "$LAST_FCEDIT"; exit "$s" )
$ fg<Enter>
... edit FOO to BAR and exit the editor ...
( "$_fce" "$@"; s=$?; mv "$1" "$LAST_FCEDIT"; exit "$s" )
$ <Alt-/>echo BAR<Enter>
BAR
```

> Why does this happen?

I'm not able to find a *convincing* rationale for it, but it's the same with plain `fc` (and related keybindings) on all the shell implementations I could check.

My idea is that it has do with the shell not being able to recursively background or foreground *itself*, but only its child jobs (process groups). The same thing you could notice with:

```
$ foo(){ cat; echo DONE; }
$ foo
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 cat
DONE  # but cat is still running!
$ fg
cat
^D
$
```

or

```
$ foo=$(cat)
^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z # no way to suspend it!
```

Unlike in `bash`, the first example will actually "work" in `ksh93` or `zsh`; but the second will be *unkillable* in `ksh93` or `zsh` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl-Z` triggers `SIGTSTP`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886812/whats-the-difference-between-sigstop-and-sigtstp/11888074 . `SIGTSTP` suspends the process :

> Factoid: If you're a linux programmer, SIGTSTP is what you get when
>   you use Ctrl-Z to interrupt a process running in a shell without
>   killing it. This usually causes the shell to put it on a suspended job
>   list.

*simpleusers*'s comment under first answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886812/whats-the-difference-between-sigstop-and-sigtstp/11888074

Why `SIGTSTP` suspends a process is because this is defined in the kernel, `SIGTSTP`suspends a process (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Comment: Sure, but then I un-suspend the text editor with `fg` and it works just fine. But the shell doesn't execute the temporary file afterwards. That's the question.

Comment: Try to send `SIGCONT` like in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246780/how-to-resume-a-suspended-shell/246781

Comment: I've tried this; it doesn't make the shell execute the temporary file. Besides, if it were a matter of SIGCONT, then the text editor or shell would be unresponsive; but they aren't.

Comment: Can you locate the editor in the process tree with `ps -e --forest` or print the childs with `ps -C processname` like in https://www.tecmint.com/ps-command-examples-for-linux-process-monitoring/

Comment: Possibly the signal does not reach the child processes in the terminal so the signals are only delivered to the process group of the tty, not to its childs ,see **https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149741/why-is-sigint-not-propagated-to-child-process-when-sent-to-its-parent-process**